# How to add text to an existing file in Java with UTF-16LE?

Tags: java, file, addition, utf-16, utf-16le

Hello I am searching for a way to add text to an existing file in Java.
I tried to use

```
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("planetaryData.txt", true));
```

But my file is written in UTF 16-LE so I have to proceed like this:

```
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("file.txt","UTF-16LE");
```

And the FileWriter do not accept a third argument where I can add "UTF-16LE" option.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Use an OutputStreamWriter on top of a FileOutputStream. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter-java.io.OutputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-

Comment: @JBNizet Shouldn't that be an answer?